# How to set image height & width while using xzoom.js library?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create an image zoom using  xzoom.js library? https://payalord.github.io/xZoom/#features, the issue now is that all the images are not of the same size (height and width), which means that an image with really long height and width will take up all the screen. How do i prevent this by adding height and width to the images.

this is what i have tried.

#### ***Look at this GIF to understand better the issue

### [image width & height error.gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXEg1.gif)***

html

```
<div class="large-5 column">
    <div class="xzoom-container">
        <!-- <img class="xzoom" style="border-radius: 10px;" id="xzoom-default" src="{{product.image.url}}" xoriginal="{{product.image.url}}" /> -->
        <img class="xzoom" style="border-radius: 10px;" id="xzoom-default" src="{{ product.image.url }}" xoriginal="{{ product.image.url }}" />

        <div class="xzoom-thumbs" style="overflow-x: scroll; max-width: 100%; width: auto; display: flex;">
            <a href="{{product.image.url}}">
                <img style="height: 70px; width: 100px; object-fit: cover; border-radius: 7px; margin-left: 5px;" class="xzoom-gallery" width="80" src="{{product.image.url}}" title="{{product.title|truncatechars:50}}" />
            </a>

            {% for g in product_images %}
            <a href="{{g.image.url}}"><img style="height: 70px; width: 100px; object-fit: cover; border-radius: 7px;" class="xzoom-gallery" width="80" src="{{g.image.url}}" /></a>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="large-7 column"></div>
```

script

```
<script>
    (function ($) {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            // $('.xzoom, .xzoom-gallery').xzoom({zoomWidth: 400, title: true, tint: '#333', Xoffset: 15});
            $(".xzoom, .xzoom-gallery").xzoom({
                zoomWidth: 400,
                title: true,
                tint: "#333",
                Xoffset: 15,
            });
            $(".xzoom2, .xzoom-gallery2").xzoom({ position: "#xzoom2-id", tint: "#ffa200" });
            $(".xzoom3, .xzoom-gallery3").xzoom({ position: "lens", lensShape: "circle", sourceClass: "xzoom-hidden" });
            $(".xzoom4, .xzoom-gallery4").xzoom({ tint: "#006699", Xoffset: 15 });
            $(".xzoom5, .xzoom-gallery5").xzoom({ tint: "#006699", Xoffset: 15 });

            //Integration with hammer.js
            var isTouchSupported = "ontouchstart" in window;

            $(".xzoom").css({
                width: "100%",
                height: "500px",
                objectFit: "cover",
            });

            if (isTouchSupported) {
                //If touch device
                $(".xzoom, .xzoom2, .xzoom3, .xzoom4, .xzoom5").each(function () {
                    var xzoom = $(this).data("xzoom");
                    xzoom.eventunbind();
                });

                $(".xzoom, .xzoom2, .xzoom3").each(function () {
                    var xzoom = $(this).data("xzoom");
                    $(this)
                        .hammer()
                        .on("tap", function (event) {
                            event.pageX = event.gesture.center.pageX;
                            event.pageY = event.gesture.center.pageY;
                            var s = 1,
                                ls;

                            xzoom.eventmove = function (element) {
                                element.hammer().on("drag", function (event) {
                                    event.pageX = event.gesture.center.pageX;
                                    event.pageY = event.gesture.center.pageY;
                                    xzoom.movezoom(event);
                                    event.gesture.preventDefault();
                                });
                            };

                            xzoom.eventleave = function (element) {
                                element.hammer().on("tap", function (event) {
                                    xzoom.closezoom();
                                });
                            };
                            xzoom.openzoom(event);
                        });
                });

                $(".xzoom4").each(function () {
                    var xzoom = $(this).data("xzoom");
                    $(this)
                        .hammer()
                        .on("tap", function (event) {
                            event.pageX = event.gesture.center.pageX;
                            event.pageY = event.gesture.center.pageY;
                            var s = 1,
                                ls;

                            xzoom.eventmove = function (element) {
                                element.hammer().on("drag", function (event) {
                                    event.pageX = event.gesture.center.pageX;
                                    event.pageY = event.gesture.center.pageY;
                                    xzoom.movezoom(event);
                                    event.gesture.preventDefault();
                                });
                            };

                            var counter = 0;
                            xzoom.eventclick = function (element) {
                                element.hammer().on("tap", function () {
                                    counter++;
                                    if (counter == 1) setTimeout(openfancy, 300);
                                    event.gesture.preventDefault();
                                });
                            };

                            function openfancy() {
                                if (counter == 2) {
                                    xzoom.closezoom();
                                    $.fancybox.open(xzoom.gallery().cgallery);
                                } else {
                                    xzoom.closezoom();
                                }
                                counter = 0;
                            }
                            xzoom.openzoom(event);
                        });
                });

                $(".xzoom5").each(function () {
                    var xzoom = $(this).data("xzoom");
                    $(this)
                        .hammer()
                        .on("tap", function (event) {
                            event.pageX = event.gesture.center.pageX;
                            event.pageY = event.gesture.center.pageY;
                            var s = 1,
                                ls;

                            xzoom.eventmove = function (element) {
                                element.hammer().on("drag", function (event) {
                                    event.pageX = event.gesture.center.pageX;
                                    event.pageY = event.gesture.center.pageY;
                                    xzoom.movezoom(event);
                                    event.gesture.preventDefault();
                                });
                            };

                            var counter = 0;
                            xzoom.eventclick = function (element) {
                                element.hammer().on("tap", function () {
                                    counter++;
                                    if (counter == 1) setTimeout(openmagnific, 300);
                                    event.gesture.preventDefault();
                                });
                            };

                            function openmagnific() {
                                if (counter == 2) {
                                    xzoom.closezoom();
                                    var gallery = xzoom.gallery().cgallery;
                                    var i,
                                        images = new Array();
                                    for (i in gallery) {
                                        images[i] = { src: gallery[i] };
                                    }
                                    $.magnificPopup.open({ items: images, type: "image", gallery: { enabled: true } });
                                } else {
                                    xzoom.closezoom();
                                }
                                counter = 0;
                            }
                            xzoom.openzoom(event);
                        });
                });
            } else {
                //If not touch device

                //Integration with fancybox plugin
                $("#xzoom-fancy").bind("click", function (event) {
                    var xzoom = $(this).data("xzoom");
                    xzoom.closezoom();
                    $.fancybox.open(xzoom.gallery().cgallery, { padding: 0, helpers: { overlay: { locked: false } } });
                    event.preventDefault();
                });

                //Integration with magnific popup plugin
                $("#xzoom-magnific").bind("click", function (event) {
                    var xzoom = $(this).data("xzoom");
                    xzoom.closezoom();
                    var gallery = xzoom.gallery().cgallery;
                    var i,
                        images = new Array();
                    for (i in gallery) {
                        images[i] = { src: gallery[i] };
                    }
                    $.magnificPopup.open({ items: images, type: "image", gallery: { enabled: true } });
                    event.preventDefault();
                });
            }
        });
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```